# Whys does 2 dimensional curl always measure twice the angular velocity of rotational component of velocity field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I thought I understood curl in 2 D until I saw the above statement in the manual.  Why is this necessarily true?.  I used the vector field F= <-y,x> and yes I can see when curl is calculated by using the second derivatives and subtracting them in the correct order it does in fact  = 2. But this is one example, how is it that the twist will always "double up". Intuitively the force field is twisting in both x and y but they may not be twisting in the same direction and when the stronger direction wins out why would it be double ??? Should it not be a fraction of the stronger twist since the directions are different unless it is the case they always twist in the same direction. I am convinced there is an intuition failure on my part here.

Comment: interesting answers ...i need to think about this since they are not all in agreement

Comment: The other two answers do make a good point that the curl does not really measure local angular velocity of a fluid, it is more like the angular velocity of an infinitesimal paddle wheel submerged in the fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the curl fundamentally measures the shear gradient of a velocity field rather than rotation. Suppose you have a velocity field with a uniform shear gradient:
$$
\vec{v} = -y\,\hat{x}
$$
Then the curl of this is
\begin{align}
\vec\nabla\times\vec{v} &= \partial_x v_y - \partial_y v_x\\
&= 1\, .
\end{align}
But a rotating velocity field,
$$
\vec{v} = -y\,\hat{x} + x\,\hat{y}\, ,
$$
is made of *two* shear gradients...

Comment: what's the diff between a shear and a rotation ?  the curls is always 2 time angular velocity... why? that's the question

Comment: @Sedumjoy Imagine a "paddle-wheel" in the form of a little plane embedded in a shear velocity field given by $\vec{v} = -y\, \hat{x}$. If the little plane is oriented up-down, it experiences a counter-clockwise torque. If it is oriented left-right, it feels *no* torque. This is in contrast to a fully-rotational flow, in which it would experience a torque regardless of its orientation. One interpretation of angular velocity is as a measure of the *shear* of a velocity field along a given axis. (cont'd)

Comment: @Sedumjoy (cont'd) We can imagine defining an "angular velocity" along each axis. In the shear example above, the "angular velocity" along the $y$-axis is 1, whereas along the $x$ axis it is 0. The curl of the velocity field is the sum of these two. At the center of a locally-*rotational* flow, both of these are equal and non-zero, so you get twice as much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be thinking about Green's/Stokes' theorem here. In particular, consider the circulation around the circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin. You have

$$C=\int_0^{2\pi} |-R \sin(\theta),R\cos(\theta)|^2 d \theta = 2\pi R^2.$$

Green's theorem also tells you that this is going to be

$$\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}  |\nabla \times F| r d \theta dr.$$

If $|\nabla \times F|$ is a constant $c$ then this is $\pi R^2 c$. So in this respect the $2$ is the same $2$ in the discrepancy between the area and circumference of a circle. It is geometric, not analytic, if that means anything to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between the the angular velocity of the fluid   described by the field ${\bf v}$ and the curl of ${\bf v}$, hence this factor $2$ is **purely coincidental**, and could as well be $0$ or $\pi$.

Note that ${\rm curl}({\bf v})$ is a quantity that is determined at each point ${\bf z}\in\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ by doing some subtle **local** measurements, whereas the global angular velocity can be seen only "from high above", and is not felt by the individual particles.

As an example consider the solenoidal field
$${\bf a}(x,y):=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2}, {x\over x^2+y^2}\right)\qquad(=\nabla{\rm arg})\ .$$
From high above we can clearly see that something is flowing around the origin (albeit with diminishing angular speed, as $x^2+y^2$ increases). Nevertheless one easily computes ${\rm curl}({\bf a})\equiv0$.

Comment: But this example violates the topological hypothesis that allows us to use the curl to compute global quantities.

Comment: @Ian: This is a bona fide example which does not violate anything, even less a hypothesis made nowhere.

Comment: It is a good example. But we often assume the domain is simply connected and use this assumption to connect curl and circulation.

Comment: not a coincidence , its always 2 times angular velocity.